Telegram Login Widget: Bot domain invalid on test server
I am trying to place telegram login widget. The bot is registered in Test environment but the bot shows Bot domain invalid.
The domain is set to 127.0.0.1:80 just like it says here.
The widget is places with
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" 
  data-telegram-login="samplebot" 
  data-size="large" 
  data-auth-url="/auth" 
  data-request-access="write">
</script>

Becauase my bot is registered in Test environment, I thought maybe the problem is that it cannot find my bot in production server, even worse, the bot name might be taken in the production. I tried to find how to make the login widget focus on test environment strictly. I couldn't find any documentation, but:
In the telegram-widget.js I noticed there is a
var getWidgetsOrigin = function(default_origin, dev_origin) {
    var link = document.createElement('A'), origin;
    link.href = document.currentScript && document.currentScript.src || default_origin;
    origin = link.origin || link.protocol + '//' + link.hostname;
    if (origin == 'https://telegram.org') {
      origin = default_origin;
    } else if (origin == 'https://telegram-js.azureedge.net' || origin == 'https://tg.dev') {
      origin = dev_origin;
    }
    return origin;
  };

and  https://tg.dev/js/telegram-widget.js?22 gives the same code.
The widget origin then is set to https://oauth.tg.dev/ but still I get Bot domain invalid.
I am opening my app through http://127.0.0.1/.
How would I go about running a login button for a bot in Test Env, and so the app is ran locally without any domain attached to it?
